# Can the pressure distribution seen in a Venturi tunnel be explained on a molecular level?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, aerodynamics

If we consider the flow of an ideal gas through a Venturi tunnel and we assume it to be incompressible we can show through mass conservation that the velocity must increase as area decreases and vice versa. From Bernoulli’s equation we can infer a change in pressure of the flow due to the change in velocity. From this we can deduce deduce the entire pressure distribution in the tunnel assuming we know a few initial conditions.

I find this explanation perfectly adequate from a mathematical standpoint but not from an intuitive one. I struggle to really understand why the fluid’s pressure actually changes as the particles do not ‘know’ that mass must be conserved. Clearly it is the do with the shape of the container as if the shape wasn’t changing flow conditions would remain the same. So what is it that the container walls do on a molecular level such that the fluid’s molecules experience a drop in pressure?

Comment: I'd say that the *energy* must be conserved for each particle. Then, if you expect that if you dwarf the section, the molecules will go faster, by discard the pressure lowers

Comment: also, pressure is a consequence of the concentration of molecules so u cant analyze with a single molecule

Comment: It seems that a narrowing cross section would feature encroaching sidewalls that would tend to redirect particles through collision toward the wider section.